# regex for strings optionally surrounded with quotes

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to build a regex that matches strings which are either surrounded with quotes or have no quotes at either side. Moreover, a string the regex has to match may have quotes in the middle. Here's a result of my efforts at the moment:

```
^("?+)(.*[^"])(\1)$
```

It works well with strings having quotes both at start and end, having no quotes at any side or having quotes at start only:

```
$ echo '"blah "blah" blah"' | perl -ne 'if(/^("?+)(.*[^"])(\1)$/){print "$1\n$2\n$3"}'
"
blah "blah" blah
"
$ echo 'blah "blah" blah' | perl -ne 'if(/^("?+)(.*[^"])(\1)$/){print "$1\n$2\n$3"}'

blah "blah" blah

$ echo '"blah "blah" blah' | perl -ne 'if(/^("?+)(.*[^"])(\1)$/){print "$1\n$2\n$3"}'
```

But it matches strings having quotes only at end:

```
$ echo 'blah "blah" blah"' | perl -ne 'if(/^("?+)(.*[^"])(\1)$/){print "$1\n$2\n$3"}'

blah "blah" blah"
```

Any ideas what's the problem with the regex and how to fix it?

Comment: I have difficulty understanding what precisely you are trying to match. Could you perhaps show a number of test cases in a machine-readable, tabular form that can be easily fed to a test script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last case, `("?+)` matches the empty string. `(\1)` effectively becomes a no-op: It also matches an empty string.

That leaves us with `^(.*[^"])$`. This matches because your input string has a non-`"` character at the end: a newline (`"\n"`).

You can fix this by removing the newline before running the regex (`perl -ne 'chomp; ...'`).

---

As a side note, you might want to make the middle part of your regex optional. Otherwise it won't match the empty string or a string consisting of two quotes (`""`).

Comment: Is this newline character added automatically by perl?

Comment: @revo No, it's automatically added by `echo` (unless you use the `-n` flag).

Comment: So you mean `echo -n 'blah "blah" blah"' | perl -ne 'if(/^("?+)(.*[^"])(\1)$/){print "$1\n$2\n$3"}'` should work?

Comment: @revo ... try it and see?

Comment: @revo It prints nothing here. What OS are you using? What does `echo -n 'blah "blah" blah"'` output by itself?

Comment: `echo -n` does it job perfectly but `-n` here doesn't affect output of `perl -ne ...`

Comment: @revo I don't understand what you mean by that. What OS are you using? What does `echo -n 'blah "blah" blah"'` output by itself?

Comment: If you can't get what I'm saying, keeping up this conversation is time-wasting.

Comment: @revo How do you expect my to "get" anything if you don't respond to what I'm asking?

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for pointing out the cases with empty string/string consisting of two quotes only. I overlooked them. The regex with optional middle part doesn't match empty string, though. But it works fine with a string composed of two quotes.

Comment: @revo: Why is your operating system a secret?

Comment: Not on the right track... you are mistaken. Being public doesn't mean you can jump straight into the conversation which you weren't part of, although you can start one. These two have a [*difference*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+difference). *Sorry to jump into the middle of your conversation...* is a polite beginning which you wouldn't follow since you like it the other way, hence my poor removed comment. @Borodin

Comment: @revo: Really, I would be very surprised if you can find anyone to agree with you here. If it is permitted to modify others' posts then it seems a little strange to prohibit joining in a conversation. I am also surprised, given your conduct in the comments above, that you claim to value politeness. I suggest that you should verify your misconception on [*Meta Stack Overflow*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: History shows we never had a pleasant dialogue with each other. That's why I never try to start one with you, you shouldn't try either. That way life's good, LG. @Borodin